# How to set up Spring Security to return 401 rather than login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring Security configuration like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("Business_User")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password");
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

The authentication works fine. However, if an authentication failed because of either invalid user or wrong password, a standard Spring login page is returned and the return code is 200.

This is not what I expect.

How I can config Spring Security to return 401 and an empty response body if the user failed login?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to use form login. You can remove `.formLogin()` and instead add `.httpBasic()` or another authentication strategy that you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if authentication failed spring security handle it by redirecting you to the login page but you can manage it by adding the following code:

```
    http
       .exceptionHandling()
       .authenticationEntryPoint(new org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint("headerValue"));
```

or

you can also use HttpStatusEntryPoint like this

```
   http
      .exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
```